# Python keyerror 'sapi5'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyttsx

One question of this type is previously asked but is not very helpful. I am using version Python3.6 in Windows 10 OS. I am getting an error, KeyError: 'sapi5' and During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred. 
My code is:

```py
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
print(voices)
```

And here is the stack trace:

```
 File "c:/Users/farhe/OneDrive/Desktop/PYTHON/jarvis/ai.py.py", line 2, in <module>
    engine = pyttsx3.init(sapi5)
NameError: name 'sapi5' is not defined
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Github README](https://github.com/nateshmbhat/pyttsx3):

> If you recieve errors such as `No module named win32com.client`, `No module named win32`, or `No module named win32api`, you will need to additionally install `pypiwin32`.

Comment: I tried to install pypiwin32, but it is showing that Requirement already satisfied.

Comment: You might want to check if it is installed for the same version of Python that you are using to run the script. You can also try uninstalling and reinstalling `pypiwin32`, because your error is for `win32com` while the note only mentions `win32com.client`.

Comment: Thanks @TheGamer007, it worked! You are a savior buddy. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

check if pipiwin32 is installed if not do install it and even though u have installed pipwin32 and the error still persists then try these following commands in cmd as admin

pip uninstall pyttsxx3

pip install pyttsx3==2.7

this worked for me.

and in case if your error is still erupting then try uninstalling pipiwin32 and install an older version of it.